# MongoDb aggregate the count/sum of 3 fields

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, nosql

Im trying to get a sum of content a user has liked, shared or commented.

my content model has the following structure.

```
Content = {
  _id: ObjectId(),
  author: ObjectId(),
  value: <string of post content>
  tags: [<trings>],
  likes: [array of user ids],
  shares: [array of user ids],
  comments: [{
     ContentId( of the same schema ),
     User Id
  }]
}
```

Now, id like to aggregate over the content documents, 
and get a result like this.

```
{
   likes: 20,
   shares: 10,
   comments: 5
}
```

So, in short, whenever there is a content, 
where user id is in likes array, 
likes gets incremented by 1.

Same for shares and comments.

Im not sure if this is possible with aggregation framework.
I think not, but maybe some mongodb gurus know better

Quick Edit. Partially based on first post submitted, i made this.
Now, it seems to work, but im sure there is some sort of gotcha, that im missing, since it seems too simple :)

```
db.getCollection('contents').aggregate( [


{$facet: {
      "likes": [
         {$match: {likes: ObjectId("596537d6b63edc2318ee9f0c")} },
         {$group: {
           _id : "$likes",
           count: { $sum: 1 }
         }},
         { $project: { count: 1} }
      ],
      "shares": [
         {$match: {shares: ObjectId("596537d6b63edc2318ee9f0c")} },
         {$group: {
           _id : "$shares",
           count: { $sum: 1 }
         }},
         { $project: { count: 1} }
      ],
      "posts": [
         {$match: {$and: [
             {user: ObjectId("596537d6b63edc2318ee9f0c")},
             {parent: {$exists: false} }
         ]} },
         {$group: {
           _id : "$_id",
           count: { $sum: 1 }
         }},
         { $project: { count: 1} }
      ]
  }
}]);
```

Can you spot something wrong with the code above ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below aggregation in 3.4 version.

The below query will `$group` all the documents and use `$in` operator to check if the input `user_id` is in the arrays.

For `likes` and  `shares` array, use `1` if the `user_id` is found else is set `0` and `$sum` to aggregate over all documents.

For `comments` it is two step process as it is array of arrays.

`$group`ing step to go over the user_id's in the content document and check input `user_id` in each element and output `1` if match and else `0`.

The `comments` will have array of array values `[[1, 0], [1], [1]]` after group stage. Next step is to sum all the values to get the `comments` count using `$reduce` operator.

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "likes": {
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": [
            {
              "$in": [
                user_id,
                "$likes"
              ]
            },
            1,
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      "shares": {
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": [
            {
              "$in": [
                user_id,
                "$shares"
              ]
            },
            1,
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      "comments": {
        "$push": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$comments",
            "as": "comment",
            "in": {
              "$cond": [
                {
                  "$in": [
                    user_id,
                    "$$comment.user_id"
                  ]
                },
                1,
                0
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "comments": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$comments",
          "initialValue": 0,
          "in": {
            "$add": [
              "$$value",
              {
                "$sum": "$$this"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
  {
    $facet: {
      "LikeCategory": [
        { $unwind: "$likes" },
        { $group : {
           _id : "$likes",
           count: { $sum: 1 }
         }
        },{ $project : {
          userId : "$_id"
           _id : 0,
            count : 1

        }}
      ],
      "ShareCategory": [
        { $unwind: "$shares" },
        { $group : {
           _id : "$shares",
           count: { $sum: 1 }
         }
        },{ $project : {
          userId : "$_id"
           _id : 0,
            count : 1

        }}
      ],
      "CommentCategory": [
        { $unwind: "$comments" },
        { $group : {
           _id : "$comments.userId",
           count: { $sum: 1 }
         }
        },{ $project : {
          userId : "$_id"
           _id : 0,
            count : 1

        }}
      ]
}
}
];
```

In this way, you will be able to find out the counts. Above code may have some syntax issues, but i hope you will be able to resolve your problem.